# Problem with inflation 2016-2022 : CPI and percentage mismatch

Tags: percentages

this is my problem and i hope you can help me.
I need to calculate total inflation for the period 2016-2022 in a certain coutry. The problem is that I can't match the data, obtaining the same result using the consumer price index and the percentages of the annual change. Data:

CPI

2015 ...... 100,0

2016    ...... 99,9

2017    ...... 101,3

2018    ...... 102,5

2019    ...... 103,2

2020    ...... 103,0

2021    ...... 105,0

2022    ...... 114,2

I'm using that formula:  (CPI 2022 - CPI 2016) / CPI 2016 x 100. The result is: 14,314%. Is that correct?

Now, I want to obtain the same result only using the annual percentage change (assuming that the consumer price index is not available):

2015    ...... 100,0

2016    ...... 99,9 ......      -0,100%

2017    ...... 101,3 ......      1,401%

2018    ...... 102,5 ......      1,185%

2019    ...... 103,2 ......      0,683%

2020    ...... 103,0 ......     -0,194%

2021    ...... 105,0 ......      1,942%

2022    ...... 114,2 ......      8,762%

Trying to do this i'm not obtaining the same result. What is the correct formula? Please, can you show me how to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Percentages need to be multiplied. Indeed:

$$(1-0.1\%)\cdot(1+1.401\%)\cdots(1+8.762\%)=1.142=1+14.2\%$$

Comment: Thank you :) I did this but the result is 14.2 %... using the CPI is 14.31%. Why is there that gap?

Comment: Probably rounding errors I guess.

Comment: Doing another example, using this method, gap seems relevant... why? :(  Take a look at the other example i have posted

Comment: Suggeston: try $(\text{CPI}\,2022-\text{CPI}\,\color{red}{2015})/\text{CPI}\,\color{red}{2015}\,.$

Comment: For the second method, if you want the change from 201**6** to 2022 then you should not be multiplying by $(1−0.1\%)$ in the CPI case as that change is before 2016